# Does not work sortable function in laravel admin when get relation column

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

when I'm trying to make sorting of client.firstname for example I have an error
what should I do in this situation? Who had the same problem?
It has method $this->setRelationSort($this->sort['column']); but does not work

```
$grid->column('client.firstname',$label)->sortable();
```

> ErrorException In Macroable.php line 102 :
>
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::client does not
>   exist. (View:
>   /Users/andreykasamara/code/caregivers/resources/views/admin/grid/table.blade.php)

Comment: Please paste your model codes

Comment: why don't use orderBy method